# Where was MS-DOS used?

Tags: history, ms-dos

How widely was MS-DOS used?  Was it globally, or just in some specific places?

Were there any regional substitutes used more commonly, and if so, what were they?

Comment: I fear that this question will be too broad here as well.  A question about DOS regions and localizations may be more on-topic.

Comment: Before Windows 95, MS-DOS had pretty much the role that Windows has today.

Comment: MS-DOS was independently a flagship PC OS from 1981 to 1995, so I think this would be broad based on time period alone, even without considering regions, localisations and architectures — Microsoft adapted it for several x86 machines that were not IBM compatible, hoping to be the new CP/M even before fully-compatible clones sort of did that for them.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, maybe narrow it down to one question?

Comment: Interesting related read (from 1989):  https://books.google.se/books?id=JIAGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=chinese+msdos&source=bl&ots=j-is9Xifo5&sig=PpxqZt65wh8u8eO8gN6_o-5nudM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitgcSFq8PZAhVC2aQKHfGWA00Q6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=chinese%20msdos&f=false - especially chapter 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5813/where-was-ms-dos-used#comment14183_5813) by [Tommy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4147/tommy), MS-DOS (or PC-DOS on IBM computers) was the default operating system for x86 PCs from 1981 to 1995 (and still widely used for a few years after that). Early versions were also adapted by OEMs to run on hardware which wasn’t quite IBM-compatible. As such, it was used pretty much everywhere PCs were used, whether it supported the local customs or not — many users around the world made do with an English-based computing environment, even if English wasn’t their native language.

MS-DOS itself ended up supporting a variety of localisations natively, but some markets had their own versions — examples include Arabic, Hebrew, Japanese (with the [DOS/V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS/V) effort), and Russian. The Japanese market in particular was quite different from the US-based DOS market, with a different “standard” for computers ([PC-98](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-98)) and specific software.

Comment: My first job as a programmer, I had a Zenith Z-100 (I think) and it had the unique capability of dual boot, and dual processor!  It had a Z-80 processor you could boot to CP/M and an 8088 (or 86?) processor you could boot to Z-DOS.  Zenith even had their own ZBASIC flavor of MS-BASIC.  We had a wide variety of non-IBM compatibles, like Televideo, etc., that ran MS-DOS but I believe Zenith was the only one that had it's own labelled version.

Comment: You're forgeting about CP/M86 which was quite successful and it's follow up DOS-Plus, for example preinstalled with Amstrad PC1512 and several other machines.